# Can a URI variable ever be malicious

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, uri, xss

Given the following simple code:

```
 function loadthis ($var)
 {
      $id = $this->model->get_id($var);
 }
```

**Question:** can any malicious code ever be passed via a URI variable?

**Scenario:**  www.mydomain.com/mycontroller/loadthis/dosomethingreallybadhere

**Extra info:**

- I use active record on the model, so I know they cant do SQL injection
- In this example I am NOT using the form_validation class (but I use it in other places for my forms)
- I limit my URI characters to the default ones provided by Codeigniter

  ```
  $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
  ```

Comment: I've improved my question AlphaMale - see the scanario - can that in any way be some sort of malicious code?

Comment: dots slashes and tilde characters are useful in directory traversal and local file inclusion attacks. Colons are useful in constructing attacks that result in redirecting the user to arbitrary websites or remote file inclusion attacks. percent characters are useful in injection into sql where clauses. There are many more examples. Any data from the user can be malicous, whether in the URL, cookies, POST data, HTTP headers or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't too much you can do with the characters allowed ... mainly what you are attempting to prevent is anyone injecting MySQL or possibly malicious scripts into your site. There is always a possibility but I think you are fairly safe with what you have. The main things you want to filter are:

1. Quotes, Single Quotes, and Semi colons since these can be used for a MySQL injection attack.
2. HTML markup characters such as < or > since these can be used to inject malicious scripts.

This is by no means a end all list. These are the primary things you should be on the lookout for. I would highly recommend you read up on security best practices at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

"Data" by itself is never dangerous, it's just data. It depends on what you do with it that may have unwanted consequences if the data contains something you did not expect. So, for data received via the URL, or really *any* data received from somewhere the *user has control over*, you cannot know or guarantee what that data contains. Hence, do not write code that uses this data and will either break or open security vulnerabilities should that data contain something you did not anticipate.

Data with unknown content is not dangerous if you treat it as an alien object and handle it accordingly. It *is* dangerous if you treat it as if you know what's in it, even though you don't. Yes, that's a convoluted answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the code, of course. You can't never say "it's perfectly safe" without analysis all the code base. Your restricted URL charset seems reasonable (if it's sufficient for your application). However I can imagine at least one example where the input could be malicious, if the user puts `\..\..\` in the URL, which could in some case open a custom file (on Windows).

If you are only concerned about SQL injection, if you have a code like this:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = $id
```

Malicious user can set $id to `0 or 1 like 1` which passes your restricted charset.

The same can be done for XSS, if you somewhere forget to escape properly (happens often in generated JavaScript code), but the example is harder to think of.

Anyway, there is no true/perfect/safe way to restrict user input to get security. The only way to avoid XSS/SQL/whatever injection, is to go through all your code and make sure that wherever you either use for input or *output* some variable, it is properly escaped according to the used context. The rule is **don't restrict input, but be prepared that is can contain anything**.

If the input is a string, be prepared is can contain any characters and deal with it. Save it into the database *as it is*, and make sure that during the saving it can't do any harm. If you need to escape it when building the SQL query, escape it in there. If you need to put the string (or part of it) into a HTML output, escape it properly. Of course you need to be very careful to make sure you do proper escaping at all places.

Comment: my codebase is the Codeigniter PHP framework. It has protection against SQL injection already - so I'm not worried about that - just wondering if the scenario above is 'secure'

Comment: As I said, you can't say if it's secure, unless you examine the whole codebase. Your approach seems reasonable and probably is a good start, but there can always be bugs elsewhere. Your scenario seems OK, but whether it is 'secure' depends on what you exactly do with the variables.